# WCF service with 2 Bindings and 2 Base Addresses

Tags: .net, wcf

I have written a WCF service (I am a newb) that I want to provide 2 endpoints for (net.tcp & basicHttp)  The problem comes when I try to configure the endpoints.  If I configure them as seperate services, then my service names are the same which causes a problem.  I have seen recomended creating shim classes (classA : MyService, and ClassB : MyService) but that seems smelly.

```
        <services>
        <service name="MyWcfService.MyService"
                         behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfService.HttpBehavior">
            <endpoint name="ApplicationHttp"
                                address="Application"
                                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding"
                                contract="MyWcfService.Interfaces.IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex"
                                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/MyWcfService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
        <service name="MyWcfService.MyService"
                         behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfService.MyBehavior">
            <endpoint name="Application"
                                address="Application"
                                binding="netTcpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="SecuredByWindows"
                                contract="EmsHistorianService.Interfaces.IApplicationHistorianService" />
            <endpoint address="mex"
                                binding="mexTcpBinding"
                                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:49153/MyWcfService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

I have tried using a single service with the base address integrated into the address, but that gives me errors as well

```
        <services>
        <service name="MyWcfService.MyService"
                         behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfService.HttpBehavior">
            <endpoint name="ApplicationHttp"
                                address="http://localhost:8731/MyWcfService/Application"
                                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding"
                                contract="MyWcfService.Interfaces.IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/MyWcfService/mex"
                                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <endpoint name="Application"
                                address="net.tcp://localhost:49153/MyWcfService/Application"
                                binding="netTcpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="SecuredByWindows"
                                contract="EmsHistorianService.Interfaces.IApplicationHistorianService" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:49153/MyWcfService/mex"
                                binding="mexTcpBinding"
                                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one service (I assume you mean one service contract), and you want to expose two endpoints, then your option #2 should be the one to use.

However, I do see a few issues with your config:

```
<service name="MyWcfService.MyService"
         behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfService.HttpBehavior">
```

What does that "MyWcfService.HttpBehavior" include?? Anything that could cause trouble with net.Tcp endpoints??

```
<endpoint name="ApplicationHttp"
          address="http://localhost:8731/MyWcfService/Application"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding"
          contract="MyWcfService.Interfaces.IMyService" />

<endpoint name="Application"
          address="net.tcp://localhost:49153/MyWcfService/Application"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="SecuredByWindows"
          contract="EmsHistorianService.Interfaces.IApplicationHistorianService" />
```

If you have one service - one service contract - then the `contract=` attribute of both application endpoints must be the same.

Either it's the first one (`contract="MyWcfService.Interfaces.IMyService"`) or the second one (`contract="EmsHistorianService.Interfaces.IApplicationHistorianService"`) - I cannto know - but it should be the same for both `<endpoint>` entries, for sure.

**UPDATE:**
@Sean: you might be misunderstanding the MEX mechanism: the tcpMexBinding will **not** show just netTcp bindings - and that's totally by design and intended. The MEX bindings are a mechanism so you can get metadata about the service and all its endpoints. Of course, both MEX endpoints will show all the application endpoints - that's their whole purpose in life. MEX endpoints give an inquiring client the (*complete and unfiltered*) metadata about the service. It's up to the client to then decide which endpoint he can and wants to conenct to.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I am working through your suggestions, and I have made it farther.  Right now my behavior is very vanilla, as for the contract difference, I was trying to make the names more generic for the example, and missed one.  

I now have the opposite issue.  Now my problem is both sets of endpoints (http and tcp) are showing up in each mex listing.  I need to filter down the list.